# Why won't my ASP.NET MVC Form post back to my controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am certain this question has been asked before and this is NOT my only form in this project, but for some reason I cannot get my `Form.Post` to work when the "submit" button is pressed on this particular form. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Note: I checked the model Contract and there are no [Required Fields]. Also, I did get it to post back using `$.ajax POST {}`, which I may need to resort to

Here is the frame for the Form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add_Contract", "Contract", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "contractForm", role="form" }))
{
   <div class=content>
      ... Content goes here
   </div> 
<input type="submit" value="Save Contract" />
}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
// Add a Contract
public ActionResult Add_Contract()
{
    var returned = new Contract();
    return View(returned);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add_Contract(Contract data)
{
    return View(data);
}
```

Here is my route.config

```
  public class RouteConfig
  {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, as I dug deeper into this issue, I figured out the issue was that I did not have any front-end validation on the data I was inputting yet, and even though I did not have any required fields in the model, I was inputting characters in a field that was set up as an integer. I discovered the issue when I created a dummy view and let the system create the scaffolding and when I tried to enter the same character data in that int field, an error popped up stating that the field must be integer. Once I added an integer in the text box, the post worked. Thanks for anyone who reviewed this post.